# How to change server port number of AgensGraph?

Tags: agens-graph

AgensGraph can not startup.

When AgensGraph installed multiple instance on same server, Some AgensGraph can't startup.

```
$ ag_ctl start
ag_ctl: another server might be running; trying to start server anyway
server starting
```

Is there config parameter about it?

Answer (score 1):

There is configuration parameter of port number on "postgresql.conf" file.

See the directory "$AGDATA", you can found "postgresql.conf" file.

```
$ grep ^#port $AGDATA/postgresql.conf
#port = 5432                # (change requires restart)
$ vi $AGDATA/postgresql.conf
<<< FIX Port Number >>>
$ grep ^port $AGDATA/postgresql.conf
port = 9999             # (change requires restart)
```

After fix port number, Restart your AgensGraph.

```
$ ag_ctl restart
waiting for server to shut down..... done
server stopped
waiting for server to start.... done
server started
```

After restart, you can access to AgensGraph on new port number.

```
$ agens -p 9999
agens (AgensGraph 2.1.0, based on PostgreSQL 10.4)
Type "help" for help.

agens=#
```